# Why does this pretty url .htaccess not work?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am attempting to pretty my URLs using an .htaccess file. I've tried a few different rules but the site keeps crashing. I've included the code that adds the public folder to the root directory as, even though it works, I suspect it might be effecting the latter code, which doesn't work.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Make /public/ part of root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.dev$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.dev$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]

# Rewrite for terms-and-conditions.php
RewriteRule ^legal$ terms-and-conditions.php [NC,L]

# NC makes the rule non case sensitive
# L makes this the last rule that this specific condition will match
# $ in the regular expression makes the matching stop so that "legalblah" will not work

# Rewrite for package.php?feature=something
RewriteRule ^package/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ package.php?feature=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: sorry for my silly question, just be sure `mod_rewrite` is installed and running? can check on apache's log (assuming you are using one). by the sound of it - *site keeps crashing* - as if some config is broken. perhaps your `htaccess` missing something somewhere or the `mod_rewrite` is not runnning.

Comment: Well the RewriteRule for making public part of the document root is working so I assume so.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^legal$ terms-and-conditions.php [NC,L]` is not running? **edit** you can [fiddle your rule](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: correct, if I navigate to mysite.dev/terms-and-conditions.php I see the page, but if I navigate to mysite.dev/legal I get a 404 not found

Comment: try the fiddle above, i tested your rule, it fires to public first instead of the legal. do note that order of the rule matters.

Comment: Great resource and solve. If you write it as an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Even if you change the order of rules, `/terms-and-conditions.php` will still be rewritten as `/public/terms-and-conditions.php`